# Gurobi C++-how to set the NonConvex parameter to 2

Tags: gurobi, c++

When I solve the model, it happen "Error 10020: Objective Q not PSD" in the end.

The gurobi website said, to resolve this issue, set the NonConvex parameter to 2.

I type "model.set(GRB_IntParam_NonConvex, 2);", but it said
"GRB_IntParam_NonConvex" undefined.

Comment: Can you check if the following example works for you? https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/examples/bilinear_cpp_cpp.html

Comment: Oh! I know this, still thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you define your model as m. Try the following where I used the parameter's name to set the value:

```
m->set("NonConvex", "2.0")
```

Comment: I'll try it, Thanks!